# Verbatim labels in legend in bokeh plots

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm trying to use `bokeh` in python for interactive analysis of my plots.

My data are stored in `pandas.Dataframe`. I'd like to have a legend with column names as labels. However, `bokeh` extracts values from respective column instead.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

output_notebook()
```

BokehJS 0.12.13 successfully loaded.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'accuracy': np.random.random(10)}, index=pd.Index(np.arange(10), name='iteration'))
df
```

output:

```
    accuracy
iteration   
0   0.977427
1   0.057319
2   0.307741
3   0.127390
4   0.662976
5   0.313618
6   0.214040
7   0.214274
8   0.864432
9   0.800101
```

Now plot:

```
p = figure(width=900, y_axis_type="log")

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p.line(x='iteration', y='accuracy', source=source, legend='accuracy')
show(p)
```

Result:
[image]

Desired output, obtained with adding space: `legend='accuracy'+' '`:
[image]

Although I've reached my goal, the method does not satisfy me. I think, there should be more elegant and official way to tell between column name and legend label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. Bokeh tries to "do the right thing" in most situations, but doing that makes for a few corner cases where the behavior is less desirable, and this is one of them. However, specifically in this instance, you can always be explicit about whether the string is to be interpreted as a [`value`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh.core.properties.value) or as [`field`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh.core.properties.field):

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value

p.line(x='iteration', y='accuracy', source=source, legend=value('accuracy'))
```